# ExpressJS - Recommended way of defining routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am stuck with kind of a silly thing. There are two possible options (actions) that the user can choose. How should the routes be defined or what's the recommended way of defining in this case?

Paths:

```
.com/email/register
.com/email/verify
```

**Variant 1**: Keeping every route separate on a new line

```
app.VERB("/email/register", SomeObject.register);
app.VERB("/email/verify", SomeObject.verify);
```

**Variant 2**: Keeping all the options in one block (callback)

```
app.VERB("/email/:action", function(req, res) {
    var action = req.params.action;

    if (action === "register" || action === "verify") {
        SomeObject[action](req, res);
    }
    else {
        res.send(404);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your use case, but if you've only got two options I'd recommend the first variant,

```
app.VERB("/email/register", register_handler)
app.VERB("/email/verify", verify_handler)
```

The second method is useful if you've got a large number of possible actions and they share similar handling code; for example, a custom API that you'll be calling through the frontend.